# Tkinter highlightcolor options on Win7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, windows-7

I'm building a Tkinter GUI (Python 2.7) and running it on a Win7 machine.  One of the things I'd like to do is have controls such as buttons & checkboxes take on a different color when they're highlighted (in that the highlight marker itself is a little faint, especially with the default gray background).  However, setting `highlightcolor` to a distinct color (e.g. `'cyan'`) isn't having any effect on the GUI; the control remains gray whether it has the focus or not.  As a cross-check I tried setting all the `highlightblah` options to something different, but still it shows as gray, with no discernible change in the thickness either.

Is this just a limitation of Tkinter on Win7?  Does it just not respond to these options?

Comment: Not sure this will answer your question hope it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264819/how-to-change-colors-of-multiple-widgets-after-hovering-in-tkinter

Comment: No, that one's only talking about background color (bg).  I'm looking for a color change associated with gaining/losing the focus (i.e. highlight).

Comment: Tried this on Linux. It appears `highlightcolor` is meant to change the frame/surroundings of the widget, not the background itself, so the documentation is highly misleading there.

Answer (score 3):

here is an example for normal buttons:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

class HighlightButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        # keep a record of the original background colour
        self._bg = self['bg']
        # bind to focus events
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self._on_focus)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self._on_lose_focus)

    def _on_focus(self, event):
        self.configure(bg=self['highlightcolor'])

    def _on_lose_focus(self, event):
        self.configure(bg=self._bg)

root = tk.Tk()
hb = HighlightButton(root, text='Highlight Button', highlightcolor='cyan')
hb.pack()
t = tk.Text(root)
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

so this adds bindings to react to gaining or losing keyboard focus, you could expand on this to e.g. change the colour of the text also. it should be relatively straightforward to adapt this for checkbuttons.

Comment: i've just realised this isn't quite what you asked for, but i think its the best i can do, its not just python 2.7 though, same issue with 3.7 on windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple example for what u want

```
from Tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from random import choice


class TestColor():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.button = Button(self.root, text = "buggton", command = self.ChangeColor, bg = "green", fg = "Black", activebackground = "Red", highlightbackground="Black")
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.RanDomiZeColor = ["blue", "black", "white", "yellow"]
        self.root.mainloop()

    def ChangeColor(self):
        self.button = Button(self.root, text = "buggton", command = self.ChangeColor, bg = choice(self.RanDomiZeColor), fg = choice(self.RanDomiZeColor), activebackground = choice(self.RanDomiZeColor), highlightbackground = choice(self.RanDomiZeColor))
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)

try: TestColor()
except Exception as why: print why; sleep(10)
```

It's working 100% on Windows 10. so try it on Windows 7
I set the color to random so u can define every one with ur "color" to understand what's happened also it's `highlightbackground` not `highlightcolor`

Comment: This isn't really a helpful example... it instantiates a new button with every click, the new button sits directly over top of the old one(s) and covers it/them up, and there's just too much "noise" overall from applying a random color change to every color option instead of only the highlight color options that I'm concerned with.  And, all that said, it's not accomplishing what I originally asked for on Win7:  there is still no color change happening to the button(s) when I move the highlight on or off of them.